# How to make magento faster from pub/index.php to custom api method?

Tags: magento2

I found a problem through debugging. When I debug it very slowly From pub/index.php to my custom api method.I want to fix and make faster,but I dont't know how to start.

vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php (116 rows dispatch) -> vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php
->vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php

Comment: Specify the issues into some more details.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide speed up suggestions.